# Is there a workaround to create multiple funnels for the same goal in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Background:
In Google Analytics, we have created a goal funnel showing each step towards the completion of a purchase on our website. There are several steps in our transaction process, and we are using a funnel to track where users dropoff. The transaction steps occur in modals where the URL does not change, so we are using virtual pageviews so that the funnel can track each modal screen as a step towards the destination goal.

The Problem:
The problem we are having is that there are three different pages on the site where a transaction can begin, and we want to understand how our conversion rate compares whether the transaction starts on page A, B, or C. We are trying to do this without having to create three separate goals with a funnel for each.

Is there a way to capture this in a single goal?
It doesn't seem like we can create multiple funnels for a single goal; but if we could filter to identify the page on which transactions began in a report after the fact, that would work.

Is there any way to do this, or will we need to create a separate goal for each page on which the transaction can begin? Note that the transaction process is the same irrespective of the starting page, it is just the starting page that is different.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You may want to look into sequence segments for this. Rather than reinventing the wheel, good article from Bounteous regarding these in relation to conversion data
https://bounteous.com/insights/2016/04/04/more-accurate-conversion-data-sequence-segments/

Comment: "The tool for this job is a sequence segment. Sequence segments say: “Show me the data for all the sessions where X happened, and then Y (e.g. a goal completion) happened later.” You specify conditions for each step, and each step must occur in order."

That's exactly what we are trying to do! Thank you very much -- I will give it a shot now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/